# Which functions are linear combinations of irreducible characters for a given field $\Bbbk$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then it is well known that a function $f\colon G\to \mathbb C$ is a linear combination of irreducible characters iff it is constant on conjugacy classes.  What is the corresponding result for an arbitrary field $\Bbbk$, i.e., which $\Bbbk$-valued mappings on $G$ are $\Bbbk$-linear combinations of irreducible characters over $\Bbbk$?  I am assuming neither characteristic $0$, nor algebraically closed.  I expect the answer is well known and involves the characteristic and which primitive roots of unity exist. Any references are greatly appreciated.

<strike>A more specific question:  Is it true that if $f\colon G\to \Bbbk$ is constant on conjugacy classes and is constant on cyclic subgroups, then it is a linear combination of irreducible characters over $\Bbbk$?</strike>

Comment: What do you mean by "constant on cyclic subgroups"? Every element is contained in a cyclic subgroup, every subgroup contains the unit element....

Comment: You should clarify whether you
mean characters of reps over C or over K.

Comment: Sorry the second question is not what I meant. Let me delete it until I can reformulate. 

Comment: The name Berman comes to mind 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as talking of $k$-linear combinations of traces of $k$-representations of $G.$ Note that such a function must not only be constant on conjugacy classes, but should also be constant on $p^{\prime}$-sections, where $k$ has characteristic
$p.$ Recall that every element of $G$ may be written uniquely in the form $g = ab = ba,$ where $a$ has order a power of $p$ and $b$ has order prime to $p.$ The element $b$ is called the $p^{\prime}$-part of $g.$ Two elements of $G$ are said to be in the same $p^{\prime}$-section of $G$ if and only if their $p^{\prime}$-parts are conjugate. I think this reduces us to the case where $G$ is a cyclic $p^{\prime}$-group, using Brauer's or Conlon's induction theorem.
 I think you may find the necessary analysis of that case in the 1962 book of Curtis and Reiner.
 Expanded edit: The work (of Berman I believe, if my memory is accurate), I am alluding to, 
deals with the fact that dealing with traces of $k$-valued representations forces some equality of traces at group elements at elements which are not $G$-conjugate. We can assume, as I indicated, that $|G|$ is coprime to char $k$ if char $k \neq 0$. So, for example, if $\theta$ is the trace of a $k$-representation and $k$ has $q$ elements, then we must have $\theta(g) = \theta(g^{q})$ for all $g \in G.$ Similarly, if $k = \mathbb{Q},$ and $\theta$ is the trace of a $\mathbb{Q}$-valued representation, we must have $\theta(g) = \theta(h)$ whenever $\langle g  \rangle = \langle h \rangle.$
 So, let us say that $g$ and $g^{m}$ are $k$-conjugate if $\theta(g) = \theta(g^{m})$ whenever $\theta$ is the trace of a representation over $k.$ Then a $k$-valued class function $\psi$ of $G$ is said to respect $k$ if $\psi(g) = \psi(g^{m})$ whenever $g$ and $g^{m}$ are $k$-conjugate. Then the best you can hope for is that the traces of $k$-representations span the space of $k$-valued class functions which respect $k,$ and this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Geoff, doesn't this assume $\Bbbk$ is algebraically closed?  For example, this doesn't help me in the case $\Bbbk=\mathbb Q$.  I don't believe it is true that every rational valued class function on a group is a linear combination of traces of representations over $\mathbb Q$ because surely Schur index plays a role.

Comment:  I agree that Schur index plays a role, but since you only asked about k-combinations, I don't see that that matters. If you had demanded integrality, it would have mattered. Sure, if $\psi$ is the trace of a $\mathbb{Q}G$-representation, it may be that `$\psi= m_{\mathbb{Q}}(χ)$`-times the sum of thealgebraic conjugates of some complex irreducible character $\chi$. But in any $\mathbb{Q}$−linear combination of rational class functions, all algebraic conjugates of $\chi$ show up with the same multiplicity, and all have the same Schur index. 

Comment: Geoff, I am interested in Q-linear combinations of traces of reps over Q, for example. Suppose that I take a complex irreducible character which takes rational values but is not a character of a Q-rep (say the Schur index is greater than 1). It seems clear to me that this is not a Q-linear combo of Q-characters by using the inner product. So which rational valued class functions are?

Comment: I don't see your problem, if you only want $\mathbb{Q}$-combinations. I could see a problem with $\mathbb{Z}$-combinations For example, the degree $2$ complex irreducible character of the quaternions is not the character of a $\mathbb{Q}$-representation,  but it is half the character of a $\mahbb{Q}$-representation. 

Comment: @Geoff. Here is what I don't get. Take a cyclic group of prime order. It had 2 irreducible reps over Q the trivial one and the natural action on the cyclotomic field. So the irreducible Q-characters span a 2-dimensional space. So they clearly cannot span all Q-valued functions on this group. What am I missing?

Comment: OK, I see what worries you. But I did not say or imply that you got all $\mathbb{Q}$-valued class functions and the Schur index is not an issue, for the reason I gave: I'll discuss the rational case, teh case of a cyclic group of order prime to the characteristic, or other fields of characteristic zero,  is similar. If the field is smaller than splitting, you have accept forced equality of character values. So in the rational case, you only get class functions which take equal values on elements generating the same cyclic subgroup, but you get all such classfuncions and no more.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. What I had meant in my crossed-out question is exactly that it be constant on elements generating the same cyclic subgroup. I will reread your answer carefully and then most likely be satisfied and accept. 

Comment: @geoff, Is there a hope to describe k-conjugate in a way that doesn't mention traces, say in terms of the roots of unity in k?

Comment: Yes, but you have to work it out for each $k.$ I did the case $\mathbb{Q}$ and finite $k$. For number fields, you have to figure out
when $x^{h}-x$ has a root i $k,$ which may be more work, but is doable.

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted: something involving roots of unity in the field. 

Comment: Berman's paper has what I want. 